PostScript: Suppress/hide charpath outline
The following PostScript code generates the y axis of a diagram.
I just need the charpath for getting the bounding box of the text to align it.
How can I prevent the charpath from being be shown?
%!PS
/Helvetica 20 selectfont
200 200 translate
0 50 200 {
  dup
  dup
  dup
  0 exch moveto
  20 0 rlineto
  stroke
  0 exch moveto
  (    ) cvs true charpath pathbbox
  3 1 roll
  4 1 roll
  sub -2.4 div
  3 1 roll
  sub -2 mul 10 sub
  exch
  rmoveto
  (    ) cvs show
} for


I would also welcome more elegant solutions for drawing the y axis.

replace (    ) cvs true charpath pathbbox with gsave (    ) true charpath pathbbox grestore . Note that (    ) cvs should not be necessary as (    ) is a string already, cvs should be a NOP here

Thanks, this does exactly what I was looking for! Without (   ) cvs, however, it wouldn't work. I think it is needed, because the variable on top of the stack is the integer loop variable.

hm, when you write (   )  then that string should be at the top of the stack

I totally agree with you and indeed had no conversion of integer to string with cvs before, but this didn't work. When I remove this keyword from my code/file, visualization fails.
